# How to narrow a string type into one of a value of a discriminated union?

Tags: typescript

I use a third party library `react-toast-notifications` and its function `addToast` :

```
addToast(
    <div className="text-lg">
      Error here 
    </div>,
    toastConfig.error,
  )
```

The toastConfig variable is like so :

```
export const toastConfig = {
  error: {
    appearance: "error",
    autoDismiss: true,
    transitionDuration: 400,
  },
}
```

What is not great, is that the TS compiler complains :

```
Argument of type '{ appearance: string; autoDismiss: boolean; transitionDuration: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
  Types of property 'appearance' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AppearanceTypes | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

What I understand is that the "error" value, is not known as a value of `AppearanceTypes`.

The AppearanceTypes type definition of `react-toast-notifications` is :

```
export type AppearanceTypes = 'error' | 'info' | 'success' | 'warning';
```

The options itself, has this type definition :

```
export interface Options {
    appearance?: AppearanceTypes;
    autoDismiss?: boolean;
    id?: string;
    onDismiss?: (id: string) => void;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

What is my best option in a case like this?

I tried a "as" operation, which is ok but is this the good way to go or an awful hack ?

```
export const toastConfig = {
  error: {
    appearance: "error" as AppearanceTypes,
    autoDismiss: true,
    transitionDuration: 400,
  },
}
```

Is there a mean to retrieve the different values of the discriminated union ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `as` keyword like this can lead to errors on your code... For example, supose you misspeled the word `"error"` as `"eror"`, you would write something like this

```
// WRONG CODE. DO NOT COPY THIS!
export const toastConfig = {
  error: {
    appearance: "eror" as "error",
    autoDismiss: true,
    transitionDuration: 400,
  }
};
// WRONG CODE. DO NOT COPY THIS!
```

And TS would just accept it as correct, when there's clearly an error...

So, it's better to avoid using `as` keyword like this when you can.

That said, the best way to solve your problem is by explicitly declaring `toastConfig` with type `Options` like

```js
export const toastConfig: Options = {
  error: {
    appearance: "error",
    autoDismiss: true,
    transitionDuration: 400,
  }
};
```

This way, if you misspell a value on `appearance` like `"eror"` instead of `"error"`, TS will warn you.

Another way to go is by using the special cast `as const`, which casts `"error"` from the `string` type to the union type `'error'`. This would be like this

```
export const toastConfig = {
  error: {
    appearance: "error" as const,
    autoDismiss: true,
    transitionDuration: 400,
  }
};
```

Both options are type safe, but the first one is more explicit on what you're trying to do and leads TS to report a possible error sooner.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer ! However, in typing explicitly as Options, that don't prevent me from mispelling "error" value, at least in my configuration :/

Comment: The "as const" alternative, detects when an appearance value is misspelled so I have preferred this solution.

Comment: In your configuration, TS accepts "eror" as type "error"? That's weird...

Answer (score 1):

Use a ["const assertion" (`as const`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). It asserts to TypeScript that your string is not meant to change, so TypeScript will infer the type as `"error"` (etc) rather than `string`.

```
export type AppearanceTypes = 'error' | 'info' | 'success' | 'warning';

let val1 = "error";          // type = string
let val2 = "error" as const; // type = "error"

let val3: AppearanceTypes = val1; // broken
let val4: AppearanceTypes = val2; // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCYUEMpYHYDGwAKssAM5wC8cA5MFFNLXAD50CWeAZhC+7XIBXAkXLl+dAO448XAOa0A3ACgVAG2DwAblnUBGanABEDJlGNK41m7YD0dhGSPkYUBRq1xd6gExHTRmhjOCxKAgg8VysHJxQAs2C1TR09AGYALnRMYBx8IlIUShoffRjHACMmAGtgPE9U9QAWLIxsXEISMmLvPV9yuAhqoA)